# Difference in Engaged Users (Facebook page) and Engaged Users (Insights API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

We have a tool connecting with the Facebook Insights API to grab various metrics (Likes, Comments, etc).

One such metric is the Lifetime Engaged Users.

However, we've looked at many FB pages (not going through the API) and the insights numbers seem to be different.

I have used the Graph Explorer to check if there is an error in our request, and this is not the case. For example, in one case, the call returns "13480".

Here is the screenshot from the Insights page:

[FB Insights Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJDy.jpg)

I may not be checking at the correct numbers, but can someone help me out?

I would like to figure out how I can find this particular metric, other than using our tool or using the Graph Explorer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: go recheck your call to API, remove that S from "metricS=metricName".

I met this problem today, and find that there are two ways to get object insight data:

1. object-id/insights/metricNameA,metricNameB
2. object-id/insights/?metric=metricNameA,metricNameB

I happened to use the 2nd way, and wrongly typed metricS instead of metric, which led to return an array of data for all metrics, and my code data[0].values[0].value therefore got the first metric in that array which is "post_story_adds_unique", if you have same mistake as mine, that 13480 could be this 1st metric return by default from FB.